# simulink model as GAZEBO plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all

Is it possible to connect simulink to gazebo as a plugin ?
for example if i like to model a nonlinear spring using simulink
and include it as part of my robot ?

Does anyone have an idea if and how it can be done ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7399/simulink-model-as-gazebo-plugin/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/726/dmeltz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 127 on 2014-11-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

i didn't made anything like that for Gazebo, but i suppose what you need is Gazebo model plugin which will communicate with Matlab. Communication itself can be done in different way i think, e.g. all kind of: pipes, IPC, udp over network, etc.

[Call MATLAB Functions from C and C++ Applications](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html)

[C/C++ Wrapper for SIMULINK models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343942/c-c-wrapper-for-simulink-models)

Also you can probably split this task in two pieces and communicate using gazebo topics, than you need to implement Simulink S-Function block which will publish data you need to model plugin. E.g something like that:

[ROS/Matlab Simulink communication](http://answers.ros.org/question/12542/rosmatlab-simulink-communication/)

And connect this block to the outputs of your model.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [kpykc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/563/kpykc/) with karma: 88 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francis123](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2880/francis123/) on 2017-01-20**:
I can say first hand, that trying to use gazebo functionality within a S-function will not work. At run time the library libgdal.so.1 will have a couple undefined symbols to a library (cannot remember the name lets call it libA.so) and you cannot symbolically link to libA.so from an external directoy that can resolve the undefined symbol because libA.so already exists within the matlab directory and it has slightly different definitions that are needed by other libraries within matlab.

**Comment by [Francis123](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2880/francis123/) on 2017-01-20**:
^ Adding to the previous comment, if anyone has figured a way to get passed needing to use libgdal with gazebo on a ubuntu installation please give some insight :)